# __() function inside html tags

Tags: translation, language

```
sprintf(<span style="display:block;margin:4px 0 0;line-height:1.25em;font-size:95%%"> Image credit: %$s</span>
esc_html( $credit ));
```

I would like to add `__()` function to translate Image Credit text.

```
sprintf(<span style="display:block;margin:4px 0 0;line-height:1.25em;font-size:95%%"> __('Image credit:','myTheme'); %$s</span>
esc_html( $credit ));
```

Comment: <span style="display:block;margin:4px 0 0;line-height:1.25em;font-size:95%%"> . __( 'Photo credit:','myTheme' ) . %4$s</span>

Comment: the above is the actual code....

Comment: What's your question or what problem, specifically, are you experiencing?